# SPARQL query not retrieving the individuals in protege 5.0

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, ontology

i am working on protege 5.0 tool i downloaded the ontologies i.e doid.owl and cpr.owl which is freely downloadable from the web then i merged them. and i tried querying the ontologies using a SPARQL query the basic "select *" query is working but for retrieving the individuals, i have a query which is not working.. since cpr.owl is the benchmark i merged the ontology into that
the query is:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

PREFIX rs:<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/doid.owl> 

PREFIX ab: <http://purl.org/cpr/0.9>

SELECT ?name ?age ?address

WHERE 

{ ?person ab:hasDisease "heart_cancer";

                  ab:Name ?name ; 

                  ab:Age ?age ;

                  ab:Address ?address. }
```

[image: hierarchy showing patient's individuals]

[image: hierarchy of a disease]

Comment: `PREFIX ab: <http://purl.org/cpr/0.9>` looks very suspicious.  It means that **ab:Name** in `ab:Name ?name` is `http://purl.org/cpr/0.9Name`.  Are you sure that's not supposed to be `PREFIX ab: <http://purl.org/cpr/0.9/>` with a final slash?

Comment: And similarly, perhaps `PREFIX rs:<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/doid.owl>` should have a `#` at the end?

Comment: yeah i added even that # in the uri..  then also its not working!!                                                        PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX doid:<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/doid#> 
PREFIX cpr: <http://purl.org/cpr/0.9#>
SELECT ?name ?age ?address
WHERE 
{ ?person cpr:hasDisease "heart_cancer";
                  cpr:Name ?name ; 
                  cpr:Age ?age ;
                  cpr:Address ?address. }